# Apollo GraphQL detect subscription started

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, apollo-client

I use `graphql-ws` to subscribe to GraphQL events. I use Observable interface to listen to the events. using `error` callback we can detect that subscription is failed to start, But there is no way to detect that it's successfully started

`next` happens when we get an event, But I would like to wrap the `Observable` with a `Promise` and await for it to start subscription

And while the promise is not resolved, I want to show a progress bar. I can reject the promise in the `error` but I couldn't find anyway to `resolve` it when server returns response to the subscription request

```js
function toObservable(operation) {
  return new Observable((observer) =>
    client.subscribe(operation, {
      next: (data) => observer.next(data),
      error: (err) => observer.error(err),
      complete: () => observer.complete(),
    }),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor the connection state when creating the client:

```js
    const _wsClient = createClient({
        url: process.env.GRAPHQL_WS_ENDPOINT!,
        on: {
            connected: () => {
                console.log("_CONNECTED!!!")
            },
            closed: () => {
                console.log("_CLOSED!!!")
            },
            error: () => {
                console.log("_ERROR!!!")
            }
        },
    })
```

The docs mention more events you could listen at, when using 'on'
https://the-guild.dev/graphql/ws/docs/interfaces/client.ClientOptions#on

Maybe it doesn't integrate with the Promise approach you mentioned, but you could use a global state handler like redux or a global scoped observable to share the connection state among instances/components

Comment: The "connected" is not equal to "subscribed". connected means websocket connection is established